# Which law in Australia prevent sunscreen manufacturers from displaying the PPD ratings on their sunscreens?

Tags: australia, health

I read on https://labmuffin.com/sunscreen-review-2-bioderma-la-roche-posay/:

> The Canadian version has a PPD (UVA protection factor) of 42. Interestingly, even though there’s a known PPD value for the Australian version, they’re not allowed to publicise it due to some weird regulation.

Which law in Australia prevent sunscreen manufacturers from displaying the persistent pigment darkening (PPD) ratings on their sunscreens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There isn't one

Cosmetics (including sunscreens) are regulated by the National Industrial Chemicals Notification and Assessment Scheme (NICNAS) under the *[Industrial Chemicals (Notification and Assessment) Act 1989](https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/C2016C00816)* (the IC(NA) Act) and the *[Industrial Chemicals (Notification and Assessment) Regulations 1990](https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/F2010C00477)* subject to the [regulatory guidelines](https://www.tga.gov.au/sites/default/files/sunscreens-args.pdf) of the Therapeutic Goods Administration; the responsible government agency.

In Australia, therapeutic sunscreens with an SPF rating of 4 or more and cosmetic sunscreens with an SPF rating of 30 or more *must* be broad-spectrum and comply with [AS/NZS 2604:2012](https://infostore.saiglobal.com/en-us/standards/as-nzs-2604-2012-117193_saig_as_as_267344/). Further, due to long-running (50+ years) public-health campaigns on sun danger, there is almost no [market](https://www.priceline.com.au/search/?q=sunscreen) for therapeutic sunscreens less than 50+ or cosmetic ones less than 30.

So, since almost all sunscreens in Australia are broad-spectrum, the SPF incorporates the information contained in the PPD and since there is a requirement to publicize the SPF and no requirement for PPD, sunscreen makers don't.